# Inline window for a YouTube video

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, youtube

I have an image surrounded by a link:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0"><img src="image.png"></a>
```

I want to open this link in a new window, like what I found in this site: http://www.licensario.com/

You recognize it by the play button that it has. Press on it and an inline windows will appear.

I think they using `jquery-youtube-tubeplayer`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source of the mentioned website, they using [LightBoxMe](http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/) for the inline window, which is a jQuery plugin in combination with [TubePlayer](https://github.com/nirvanatikku/jQuery-TubePlayer-Plugin) (and [here](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin)). On each website is written how to use these scripts.